# Which real-life battles did Captain America fight in?

Tags: marvel, captain-america, warfare

Over the years, due to various retcons, Captain America seems to fought in practically every single battle in World War II. Is there a list of the real-life World War II battles Steve Rogers of the 616 comic universe fought in?

Comment: Relevant: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18107/how-did-captain-america-change-world-war-2

Comment: Are you asking about just the comics? Because in the film, the answer is **none** ([reference](https://carriev.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/captain-america/)).

Comment: @randal'thor No, as mentioned in the question, I want the original 616 comics Captain America.

Comment: @Thaddeus I don't see how this is a duplicate. Rogue Jedi is asking for a list of specific real world battles Cap was written into. The other question and answer is about Cap's overall impact on the course of the war.

Comment: There were NO real battles Captain America was written into. The answer given is as good as it gets, without getting into the metaconceptualization of the war and comic superheroes. Comics weren't trying to trivialize the war, so they didn't have superheroes appearing in real battles. The answer given was exactly the answer needed. I will open it back up if someone requests it but I doubt a better answer exists.

Comment: Captain America joined WWII before the United States did. He did not participate in real battles because the US hadn't entered the war yet. Heroes such as Captain America and Daredevil were more jingoistic tools to inspire soldiers to join the military. While many of Marvel's heroes were seen as fighting in WWII and even alongside troops, comic stories were being told by artists and writers were were not in the war, so they would never write contemporary stories of the heroes in the war during the war. Later re-tellings might do some things differently.

Comment: @Thaddeus According to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_Reborn), he fought on D-Day. So he did fight in some real-life battles.

Comment: NO. This was written in 2009. I am not talking about RETROCOGNITION where the writers go back and retroactively add him to history. If that is what is being asked, then go and hunt down the instances such as they are and tally them up. But you will find, HISTORICALLY he did no such things. This is just another Marvel way of getting your cash.

Comment: @Thaddeus It's still canon. I never stated that I only want "historical" comics. I can't tally them up myself, as I don't own that many Captain America comics, which is why I'm asking the question. If it bothers you so much, don't answer it.